# Excel - Find the date of a specific day after a specific date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

In Excel, I need to create a formula that gives me the date of the first Thursday after the beginning of the Fiscal Year. Our Fiscal year starts on 10/1. So for instance 10/1/2016 Begins the year and I want to calculate what the Thursday is on or after that date so I can programmatically create a new week each row on the Thursday after. So, if it Thursday did fall on 10/1 the rows would be 10/1, 10/8, 10/15 and on. However 10/1/2016 is on a Saturday. The first Thursday after that is 10/6/2016 How do I go about finding that Thursday date using a formula?

Comment: This is very possible. [Please show what you've tried so far.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it if the start of your fiscal year is in A1 and in your locale days are numbered from 1=Sunday to 7=Saturday:-

```
=A1+MOD(5-WEEKDAY(A1),7)
```

This didn't work for me on Excel 2007 but should be even easier

```
=A1-WEEKDAY(A1,15)+7
```

The 15 can be replaced with 10+W for other days of the week where W is the day number starting from Sunday=1.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I did come up with a solution although not quite as simple as yours. What I did was this.
`=IF((5-(WEEKDAY(FYBegin)))<0,WEEKDAY(FYBegin)-2,5-(WEEKDAY(FYBegin)))`

Comment: Great. =A1-WEEKDAY(A1,15)+7 is even easier but didn't work on my ancient Excel 2007.