# Excel Qn, Formula to check if a date falls within the upcoming week.

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am trying to check if a date falls within the upcoming week.

For example, today is 9/14/2016.

The upcoming week is defined as anything that are through 9/23/2016.

I was wondering if anyone can help me with it. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you define your end of week? e.g. Is the last day Saturday, so you want to say if it's within the following Sunday Through Saturday?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming standard convention for the week is in line with Excels, (Sunday through Saturday):

```
=IF(AND(A1 >= TODAY(),A1 <= TODAY() + 6 + WEEKDAY(A1)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

This will return TRUE if the value in A1 is within the upcoming week and false if it is not.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a Between() syntax in Excel. I get error `NAME?` in Excel 2013 if I attempt to use such a function, indicating it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that 9/23/2016 is a Friday but I wasn't sure what you wanted to do if it was currently Sunday (say) and you wanted to see if a date was on or before Friday in the upcoming week - would that be Friday 5 days later or 12 days later? So I've done an answer that can be tailored however you want it:-

```
=AND(D$2>=$A3,D$2<=$A3+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY($A3),5,11,10,9,8,7,6))
```

where A3 contains the current date and D2 contains the date you're trying to evaluate.

So the numbers in the choose statement say what you want to do with each day:-

```
If Sunday add 5 days
If Monday add 11 days
```

etc. etc.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615345/excel-find-the-date-of-a-specific-day-after-a-specific-date/39615765#39615765)